# SQL Server Express much faster than SQL Server?

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express, vba

Does anyone know why SQL Server Express could be much faster that full SQL Server from VBA code? The difference is huge so I wonder if it could be in drivers? Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific to get much help. But for example is one on the local machine and one over a network?

Comment: SQL Server Express is the **same code base** as "full" SQL Server - so I would be extremely surprised if there were huge differences....

Answer (score 1):

That depends on many things. Is it running locally? Express is less demanding and probably will run better than a full fledged SQL Server install on your desktop.